# Colored SVG icons in Leaflet

Tags: svg, leaflet, icons

I have added a SVG icon to leaflet as follows:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M224 387.814V512L32 320l192-192v126.912C447.375 260.152 437.794 103.016 380.931 0 521.286 151.707 491.481 394.785 224 387.814z"/></svg>`,
});

this.myMarker = L.marker([50.505, 30.57], { icon: myIcon }).addTo(map);
```

It is showing up as expected:

[image]

Now, when you add color to the SVG as follows, the icon disappears in the map:

```
  iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M224 387.814V512L32 320l192-192v126.912C447.375 260.152 437.794 103.016 380.931 0 521.286 151.707 491.481 394.785 224 387.814z" fill="#fdbf00"/></svg>`,
```

Any thought about this?

Comment: I put this in a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yKxQCuxZ5DLeJyZk) for easier reproducibility. I think the `#` makes the XML parser choke, but replacing the colour definition with a `rgb(1,2,3)` syntax makes the icon show up as black still.

Comment: I use this [page](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) to convert svg to inline.
See `#` is replaced with `%23`, so it should look like `fill = '%23fdbf00'` in your case. 

I create colorful markers in a different way. Not through iconUrl only via html and then I use I can use hex colors without problems - [leaflet-examples](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples/blob/master/13.svg-markers-width-legends/script.js#L68)

Comment: No matter what you are replacing with ```#```. It ignores the color altogether. A tried some dummy data like ```stroke="%662dewqdwewfdbf00" ``` . The icon is showing up with black color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prepared an example instead of `iconUrl` I used `html` Then you can easily use colors in hex ;)

```js
// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZomm: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 13;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.237049;
const lon = 21.017532;

// calling map
const map = L.map('map', config).setView([lat, lon], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


const svgTemplate = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="marker">
      <path fill-opacity=".25" d="M16 32s1.427-9.585 3.761-12.025c4.595-4.805 8.685-.99 8.685-.99s4.044 3.964-.526 8.743C25.514 30.245 16 32 16 32z"/>
      <path fill="#F7FADA" stroke="#000" d="M15.938 32S6 17.938 6 11.938C6 .125 15.938 0 15.938 0S26 .125 26 11.875C26 18.062 15.938 32 15.938 32zM16 6a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8z"/>
    </svg>`;

const icon = L.divIcon({
  className: "marker",
  html: svgTemplate,
  iconSize: [40, 40],
  iconAnchor: [12, 24],
  popupAnchor: [7, -16]
});

const marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {
    icon: icon
  })
  .bindPopup('#F7FADA')
  .addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Modified @IvanSanche example below

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ],
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M224 387.814V512L32 320l192-192v126.912C447.375 260.152 437.794 103.016 380.931 0 521.286 151.707 491.481 394.785 224 387.814z"/></svg>`,
});

var myIcon2 = L.icon({
  iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M224 387.814V512L32 320l192-192v126.912C447.375 260.152 437.794 103.016 380.931 0 521.286 151.707 491.481 394.785 224 387.814z" fill="%23fdbf00" stroke="red" /></svg>`,
});

this.myMarker = L.marker([50.505, 30.57], { icon: myIcon }).addTo(map);
this.myMarker2 = L.marker([50.505, 130.57], { icon: myIcon2 }).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" /><div id="leaflet"></div>
```